# Why is Enum as an optional in a protocol requirements behaving weird?

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

The `enum` I've:

```
enum APIMethod: String {
    case GET
    case POST
}
```

I've defined a `protocol` as:

```
protocol APIResource {
    associatedtype Model: Codable
    var base: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
}
extension APIResource {
    var method: APIMethod? { // To be able to have the conforming type ignore if it wants
        return nil // Actually, this will return a valid case but not now
    }
    var request: URLRequest {
        let url = URL(string: base + path)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method?.rawValue
        return request
    }
}
```

Now when I adopt this in my `struct` I provide it's own `method` like:

```
struct MyResource: APIResource {
    typealias Model = MyCodableModelStructure
    let base = "http://---.com"
    let path = "/pathToResource"
    let method = APIMethod.POST
}
```

**But when the `request` property is computed the `request.httpMethod` doesn't get the value `"POST"`.**

---

Then I tried to do something different. I moved the `enum` requirement from the `extension` to the `protocol` itself.

```
protocol APIResource {
    associatedtype Model: Codable
    var base: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var method: APIMethod? { get }
}
extension APIResource {
    var request: URLRequest {
        let url = URL(string: base + path)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method?.rawValue
        return request
    }
}
```

As soon as I moved it to the protocol itself, I get the error:

> Type `'MyResource'` does not conform to protocol `'APIResource'`

So I was forced to redefine `MyResource` as:

```
struct MyResource: APIResource {
    typealias Model = MyCodableModelStructure
    let base = "http://---.com"
    let path = "/pathToResource"
    // See! I was forced to annotate the type
    let method: APIMethod? = APIMethod.POST
    // Or, otherwise, I tried with rawValue without annotating the type
    // let method = APIMethod(rawValue: "POST")
}
```

**At this point, the `request` property is successfully computed with `request.httpMethod = "POST"`.**

---

**Edit:**

Actually my `APIResource` is having an `associatedtype`. Being so, I created a generic class as:

```
class MyAPIRequest<T: APIResource> {
    let resource: T
    init(resource: T) {
        self.resource = resource
    }
}
```

Then I initialized `MyResource` and `MyAPIRequest` as:

```
let apiResource = MyResource()
let apiRequest = MyAPIRequest(resource: apiResource)
apiRequest.load {
    // async task with completion block
}
```

---

---

So, my question stands at:

- Why adding the property in extension didn't work at the first place?
- And why it's working when added to the protocol definition itself?
- Lastly, why I was forced to use *annotating* or `rawValue` initializer?

Comment: Change `let method: APIMethod?` into `var method: APIMethod?`

Comment: _But when the request property is computed the request.httpMethod doesn't get the value "POST"._ I did not experienced this behaviour at all... can you also show how to instantiate the struct, please?

Comment: @holex see my edit

Comment: @CZ54 that doesn't essentially solve the issue I'm having. Either `let` or `var` won't let me get rid of the type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

1. If we define any property in Extension and do not declare it in Protocol then it only pick up the extension value. Does not matter you have redefined it or not.
2. When you define it in protocol, that makes it overridable, so you can get child value.
3. Here declaration is optional and you are passing non-optional value in it. So you had to tell the type of value.

Hope this helps.